# How to format decimal thousand separator in Jinja

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I have a table with decimal numbers, which are up to 10^11, it would make sense to dislay them thousand separeted.

[image]

It seems it is not doable in CSS alone, so I tried jinja, but the usual formats dont seem to work. I have:

```
<td class='profit'>{{'%d' % row['profit']}}</td>
```

in my template, but the expected ',' separator `'%,d'`, like this:

```
<td class='profit'>{{'%,d' % row['profit']}}</td>
```

gives me error:

```
builtins.ValueError

ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 1
```

I also tried with `format`:

```
<td class='profit'>{{format(row['profit'],',d')}}</td>
```

or:

```
<td class='profit'>{{row['profit'].format(',d')}}</td>
```

which gives the same error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'float object' has no attribute 'format'
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found something that works:

```
<td class='profit'>{{'{:,}'.format(row['profit'])}}</td>
```

gives:

[image]